# Android SystemUi automatically shuts down

Tags: android, flutter, dart

```
void main() {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIMode(SystemUiMode.edgeToEdge);
  runApp(const MyApp());
}
```

I want to show the ui part like this. I wrote this code in main.dart but after showing the ui it instantly closes and shows up in full screen again. How can fix this problem?

[image: image1]

Answer (score 1):

Wrap the `Scaffold` in a `SafeArea` `widget`

Comment: Thank you, I saw where the problem was. The other programmer wrote the place you said on every page. I deleted the code and it was fixed.